# How to find actual contact form 7 structure in DB?

Tags: php, database, wordpress, contact-form-7

I want to find the actual code for all my forms (there are a lot). For example, the cf7 code looks like

```
<label>Name</label>
[text* your-name]
```

I know where the actual entries are, but I need to find the actual form structure in the db. How can I do that? Where?

I looked in `wp-content/plugins/contact-form-7` and looked at some of the php, I though I might have had a lead from viewing source code, but I guess I didn't look deep enough because I didn't find what I needed. Can anyone help me??

Comment: contact forms in CF7 are a post-type iirc, so look to the wp-post table & then cross-reference it with the post-meta table.

Comment: This was helpful. Thank you! @admcfajn

Comment: By the way in case anyone else ever reads this, the meta_key for the CF7 forms is "_FORM" so search `WHERE meta_key = '_FORM'`

Comment: there is also [this plugin](https://en-ca.wordpress.org/plugins/flamingo/) which you might find helpful if you want to display form submission in the dashboard

Answer (score 9):

If anyone stumbles upon this later... the actual form post is stored in the database in the table `wp_posts` (if your prefix is wp_) and the `post_type = wpcf7_contact_form`.  You can probably sort the rows by `post_type` since W is pretty far up the alphabet.