# Contact Form 7 (CF7) email template data storage?

Tags: wordpress, contact-form-7

I'm unable to find anything on this and hoping the community here will be able to help. When you add data to the Mail tab to set up your email template within CF7, where and how is that data stored? Just to clarify, I'm not talking about the data submitted by site visitors via the form you've created nor the form structure itself, I'm talking about the data entered via the plugin interface within the dashboard that determines where the submissions are sent to and how they are structured as mail. The interface can be seen [here](https://contactform7.com/setting-up-mail/).

I have the ongoing problem that every-time I deploy a site and update the database the fields are being wiped out, this results in submissions failing. I therefore have to manually re-enter the data after each deploy. I'm unable to find anything in the database nor do I see changes to repo in Git, so I'm confused as to how it's stored and how to ensure it doesn't get cleared.

Any help would be much appreciated.

**An update.** With thanks to @HowardE, it appears the Mail tab data **is** stored in the database. It is appended to the end of the post_content of the wpcf7_contact_form post. However, this data does not re-populate the respective fields on the Mail tab when moved.

So, for example, on my local copy of the site both the form and mail tab are populated, yet when I copy the database from local to dev, the form structure is moved and exists on dev but the mail tab is empty.

Comment: It's a post. It's stored in the database

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57044527/how-to-find-actual-contact-form-7-structure-in-db

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to find actual contact form 7 structure in DB?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57044527/how-to-find-actual-contact-form-7-structure-in-db)

Comment: Hi @HowardE no it doesn't, this refers to the actual form structure, I'm talking about the email structure as configured in the "Mail" section of the plugin control panel, please see the link I referenced for further detail. All the form structure is preserved on deployment, as I'm aware they're posts, it's the email structure that is cleared.

Comment: Yeah... it's in the post.  It's all there.

Comment: You're absolutely correct, it is there appended to the end of the post_content, I've just dug into the database, however when you move data, it doesn't then populate the mail tab. So, for instance, locally I have both the form structure and the mail tab populated. I export the DB and import it to dev in its entirety (changing only the site URL). When I then check dev, the form exists, but the mail tab is empty/blank.